# Issues if migrating a repository to a Github organisation then forking the repo?

Tags: github

I have a Github repository, lets call it:

```
http://github.com/LegoStormtroopr/ExampleRepository
```

I want to hand ownership of this repository over to an Organisation to get:

```
http://github.com/MyCoolOrg/ExampleRepository
```

But, I want to keep working on the code on my own fork. If I forked this code, I'd once again have a repository with the address:

```
http://github.com/LegoStormtroopr/ExampleRepository
```

In effect, I'd move the upstream to the organisation, make forks in a local github fork, and then be able to issue pull requests to the organisation.

I'd like to do this with the least hassle and breakages, and [the documentation on what happens after a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository/) is handed over is a little hazy.

Are there any serious issues that will happen as a result of shifting the repository like this? Will things break because a repository that was there disappeared for a short time?

Answer (score 1):

So having just given this a shot, it appears there are no issues when doing this. However a few things to note:

- The organisation cannot have a previous fork of the repository. This prevents it from being able to take ownership.
- If you transfer the repository to the organisation, and then fork this into your own account, any working copies of this don't need to be updated, however changes you make will be pushed into your repository, not the organisations.
- You may need to reconfigure third-party applications (like Travis-CI and Coveralls) to work with the new organisation, but this is straight forward:

  1. From your account, go to settings and select <kbd>Applications</kbd>:
     [image]
  2. Find the application you need to reconnect (for example Travis-CI) and click <kbd>View</kbd>:
     [image]
  3. Next to each orgnaisation there will be a button titled <kbd>Grant</kbd> (not shown because I've already clicked it):
     [image]
- **To get Coveralls working properly, in addition to the above, you also need to:**

  1. Set your visibility in the organisation to Public:
     [image]
  2. Refresh the list of repositories in Coveralls (ignore the button name, it syncs public and private repositories):

  [image]

  3. Lastly, to retain your coverage history, in Coveralls in your *old* repository select "Change source" and in the list select the corresponding repository in your new organisation.
     [image]

And now your organisation is all set!